# C# DateTime operator +=

Tags: c#, datetime, sum

I have two variables in type of DateTime, and I want to sum them, how can I do it?
I get compilation error that says DateTime dosen't have operator +=

Comment: See also the discussion [Is TimeSpan unnecessary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448976)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to answer the comment in Mehrdad's answer - yes, it looks like those should *both* be regarded as `TimeSpan`s instead of `DateTime` values... and yes, you can add time spans together too.

If you're using .NET 4, you can use a custom format string to parse the first part of the lines, e.g. "00:00:01.2187500".

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string line1 = "00:00:01.2187500 CA_3";
        string line2 = "00:00:01.5468750 CWAC_1";

        TimeSpan sum = ParseLine(line1) + ParseLine(line2);
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }

    static TimeSpan ParseLine(string line)
    {
        int spaceIndex = line.IndexOf(' ');
        if (spaceIndex != -1)
        {
            line = line.Substring(0, spaceIndex);
        }
        return TimeSpan.ParseExact(line, "hh':'mm':'ss'.'fffffff",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, what are CA_3 and CWAC_1?  Are they something standard or just the OP input format?

Comment: @Mehrdad: They're nothing I'm familiar with. I'm assuming they're unimportant :)

Comment: @aharont: Are you not using .NET 4? If not, I'm slightly surprised it *is* working as you can't specify your own format string (as far as I'm aware.)

Answer (score 8):

You cannot add two `DateTime` values together. It wouldn't have any meaning. A `DateTime` represents a single point in time, whereas a `TimeSpan` represents a duration. Adding a point in time to a duration results in another point in time. You can only add `TimeSpan` values to `DateTime` values–and it *does* support `+=` in that case:

```
dateTime += timeSpan;
```

Comment: i have those lines: 00:00:01.2187500 CA_3   00:00:01.5468750 CWAC_1
they are in a file. can i read the times as timeSpan and add them?

Comment: @ahront: `TimeSpan` has a bunch of constructors that take years, months, days, hours, ... just like `DateTime`. So yes, you should read the duration value as `TimeSpan` and add it to your `DateTime`.

Comment: @Merhrdad: Err, no. You cannot use years or months in the `TimeSpan` constructor, as they're not actual units of measure (they vary in length).

Comment: @Adam: Eh, you're right. I was nuts. You can use `days` and that should work out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTime.ToOADate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx) :

```
DateTime D1 = DateTime.Today;
DateTime D2 = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(2);

double days = D1.ToOADate() + D2.ToOADate();
```