# How do you convert an int representing days-from-zero to DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have an int representing a number of Gregorian days from Year Zero (thanks, Erlang). How do I convert this to a DateTime object? I can't create a DateTime(0,0,0), and Convert.DateTime(int) throws an invalid cast.

Comment: Err...there is no year zero in the Gregorian calendar, AFAIK

Comment: by year zero you mean 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001. or 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0000.

Comment: Ha, [this sounds familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448976/is-timespan-unnecessary)... ;)

Comment: Dan Tao: Good point, you could use TimeSpan instead of DateTime.

Comment: @Adam Robinson But there is in Erlang, it extends the gregorian calendar back to year 0, and has a fucntion to convert that to no. of days - which is likely what the OP needs to parse. One can possibly  just start a DateTime at year 1  instead and subtract a year and a month from the erlang days, or the result

Comment: @nos: Year 0 I can understand, but *month* 0?

Comment: Ha, good point about month 0 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a number, and you know the date that it represents (from Erlang), you can calculate the offset from any date you choose. Preferred is a base date in the zone that the results will be in, this will minimize calender conversion effects. (The Gregorian calendar is valid from about 1600).

If you know that offset, you can use the choosen date as the base for future calculations.

Example:

I want my offset date to be: 1/1/2000. This will be the date that I calculcate from.

I know number 37892 from erlang is actually 1/1/1970 (this is an example).

Then I can calculate the offset:

```
var myBaseDate = new DateTime(2000,1,1);

var exampleNrOfDays = 37892;
var exampleDate = new DateTime(1970,1,1);
var offset = exampleDate - myBaseDate;
var offsetInDays = exampleNrOfDays - (int)offset.TotalDays;

// Now I can calculate

var daysFromErlang = 30000; // <= example
var theDate = myBaseDate.AddDays(daysFromErlang - offsetInDays);
```

Comment: I see what you're doing there, but if I was passing in the date it represents from Erlang I wouldn't have this problem ;).

Comment: You only have to have one number and a correspending (valid .Net) date to calculate the offset. Then you can use this offset forever.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to calculate number of days from a given date. http://dotnetperls.com/datetime-elapsed

Answer (score 0):

if day zero is `0/0/0` then it is `365+30+1` day before `DateTime.Min` which is 1/1/1. So you can subtract days from year zero by `365+30+1` and add to `DateTime.Min`

Now Month 1 is January which is 31 days but what is Month 0? I assumed it is 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

With 0, you probably mean 0:00 on the 1st of January, year 1. There is no year 0 in the gregorian calendar as far as i know.

If the above is right, you can just do

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
date.AddDays(numberOfDays);
```

because the default constructor 'DateTime()' returns the "zero" DateTime object.

See the [DateTime reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/03ybds8y.aspx) for more informations.

Comment: DateTime doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: please read the documentation before downvoting. Taken from the link in the post: "By calling the DateTime structure's implicit default constructor. (For details on the implicit default constructor of a value type, see Value Types (C# Reference).)"

Comment: @bleepzter: All value types have a default constructor, `DateTime` included. You just can't call it explicitly. +1 to counter the downvote

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are aware of this, but there is a Calendar object in System.Globalization. Not only that but there is a GregorianCalendar object as well.

so try this:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
DateTime minSupportedDateTime = calendar.MinSupportedDateTime; 

//which is the first moment of January 1, 0001 C.E.

DateTime myDate = minSupportedDateTime.AddDays(55000);
//this is when you add the number of days you have.
```

Thanks,

```
Bleepzter
```

PS. Don't forget to mark my answer if it has helped you solve your problem! Thanks.

Comment: In January 1, 0001 the Gregorian calendar was not used.

Comment: However, that is a semantical representation of a standard DateTime. The calendar already returns a min value (in that semantical representation). Internally it is just a long number.